# Can I put a Python console script in a submodule?

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a Python package called `cmdline`. I use `setuptools` to define a console entry point. I would like to put this entry point inside a `cli` submodule, but I get an error when I try to run the installed script.

My project layout looks like this.

```
setup.py
cmdline/
    __init__.py
    cli/
        __init__.py
        main.py
```

The `setup.py` looks like this.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='cmdline',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=['cmdline'],
    url='',
    license='',
    author='W.P. McNeill',
    author_email='',
    description='',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['cmdline=cmdline.cli.main:main'],
    }
)
```

The `main.py` file looks like this.

```
def main():
    print("Hello, world")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Both `__init__.py` files are empty.

If I install this with `python setup.py install` and then try to run the console script, I get an error.

```
> cmdline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/envs/cmdline/bin/cmdline", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('cmdline==1.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'cmdline')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
ImportError: No module named cli.main
```

If, however, I install it via a softlink with `python setup.py develop` it works.

```
> cmdline
Hello, world
```

It also works if I don't use a `cli` submodule and just have `main.py` at the top level of the project.

How can I make the submodule configuration work?

Answer (score 2):

Your setup.py doesn't include the `cmdline.cli` subpackage, only the `cmdline` package will be included. setuptools does not recursively add all subpackages, you need to explicitly specify all packages, or use the `find_packages()` function to do so:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='cmdline',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    # or:
    # packages=['cmdline', 'cmdline.cli']
    url='',
    license='',
    author='W.P. McNeill',
    author_email='',
    description='',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['cmdline=cmdline.cli.main:main'],
    }
)
```

After that, the `cmdline.cli` package will be installed and the entry point should be resolveable.

Comment: Oops sorry. That extra `cmdline` directory above was a typo. I've edited the original question to fix it.